# Switching from set times for feeding to free feeding of a cat

Tags: cats, feeding, weight, can-food

My cat Shiloh I believe the amount of food the vet recommended is not enough for him, I picked him up tonight and he is losing weight.  The amount the vet said to use was to maintain, so it is failing to maintain his weight.  What I give him now is 1/4 of dry food in the AM, 1 small can of wet food when I get home from work.  Right now he wakes me up at 1 or 2 in the morning for more food.  So I see 2 options

1) add a third mean at night before I go to bed (1/4 dry)  I am adding 50% as I felt he has lost weight and I think he needs it back.

2) figure out how to transition him to a free feeding cat (keep the dry food out all the time for him when he wants, then a can of wet food as a treat when I get home from work in the pm.

If I am to switch to free feeding, what is the best way, would it be just put a bigger bowl down and fill it up?  Or do I want to build up to the big bowl, and if so how?

Comment: Have you talked to the vet about the fact that his recommendation does not seem to work out? Did you change the feeding-pattern (in that case, perhaps your cat is just more active than guessed by the vet?), or did the feeding-pattern stay the same and the cat suddenly started loosing weight (In that case: go to the vet, something MAY be wrong).

Comment: Something may definitely be wrong! Best to check with the vet.

Comment: Well I got Shiloh at the end of March, and that when the vet told me only 1/2 a cup of food a day.  I don't know what the feeding pattern was before I got him (I got him from the MD SPCA, if any one knows what their feeding patter is)  He is a very active cat (he loves running around and chasing things, I get tired just watching him some times)  But I will defiantly be asking the vet.

Comment: 1/4 what, cup? Also, how much does your cat weigh?  This doesn't sound like enough food for a cat of average size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Feline Obesity

Free feeding is never advised as most cats will eat more than they should, cats who are bored are also prone to consider [eating an activity](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1098612X18791877) and will indulge way more than they should.

In order to better guide you on how much to feed your cat it would be good to know how much he weighs, what he should weigh and the type of food he is on.

It is best to [feed multiple small meals a day](https://www.catvets.com/public/PDFs/ClientBrochures/How_to_Feed_Client_Broch_Final.pdf) in various locations around your house (to promote hunting) as well as using [puzzle feeders](http://foodpuzzlesforcats.com/homemade-puzzles) (environmental enrichment). Cats prefer to eat alone and in high places (reduce stress).

### Rule Out Disease

If you are feeding the correct amounts already and your cat is still losing weight it would be advised to see a veterinarian to rule out any medical issues.

Related Question: [Can I feed my cat whenever she wants?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17927/can-i-feed-my-cat-whenever-she-wants)